# HashSet Contains function not working properly

Tags: java, contains, hashset

```
while(!open.isEmpty()&& !solutionFound){
        Node selected=open.poll();//fifo
        State estado=selected.getState();
        estado.toString();
        this.exploredNodes++;       

        if(!explored.contains(selected.getState())  ){
            if(problem.testGoal(selected.getState())){
                actionSequence=recoverPath(selected, inicial);//return array with solutions
                solutionFound=true;
            }

            //totalCost++;
            successors=getSuccessors(selected);
                for(Node successor : successors){
                    //if(!explored.contains(successor))
                        open.add(successor);

                }
                explored.add(selected.getState());

        }

    }
```

I'm trying to check if the state of the selected node is inside a hashset of nodes and if it is already in it then it shouldn't do anything.

The thing is that it always returns false. And therefore compares infinitely.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object anotherState) {
    if(anotherState instanceof MazeState)return false;


            if(this.life!=((MazeState)anotherState).life)return false;
            if (this.position.x!=((MazeState)anotherState).position.x)return false;
            if (this.position.y!=((MazeState)anotherState).position.y)return false;
            if (!this.cheeses.containsAll(((MazeState)anotherState).cheeses))return false;

            return true;


}

@Override
public int hashCode() {

    return Objects.hash(this.position,this.life,this.cheeses);
```

This is my implementations of equals and hashCode which I think are fine since they compare all the attributes of the State.

Any tip would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Typo: Presumably `if(anotherState instanceof MazeState)return false;` should instead be checking if it is _not_ an instance

Comment: Also, what are `cheeses`? If this collection contains objects you defined, you also need to implement `equals(Object o)` for the `cheese`'s

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to apply a NOT check here.... So, the following will work

```java
if(!(anotherState instanceof MazeState)) return false;
```

### UPDATE

Also, a containsAll check would report two objects being equal even if the cheeses collections have elements in different order.

Comment: Love it when someone posts an answer already given on comments.

Comment: @Pants hmm...duplicates occur when different people are posting answer and adding comments around the same time while reading the question...not really an intentional thing.

Comment: That's true, but still it checks nodes that have already been explored.

Comment: Could you please share more details as in what is happening exactly?

Comment: You are doing a containsAll check which means that two Collections having same elements but in different order will result in them being reported as equal